# Awstats - LogFormat doesn't match the Amazon S3 log file contents

Tags: amazon-s3, awstats

I'm trying to setup Awstats to formate Amazon S3 log files,but it keeps saying the log doesn't match the LogFormat, below is the configuration and log content:

> LogFormat="%other %extra1 %time1 %host %logname %other %method %url
>   %otherquot %code %extra2 %bytesd %other %extra3 %extra4 %refererquot
>   %uaquot %other"
>
> 0dfbd34f831f30a30832ff62edcb8a93158c056f27cebd6b746e35309d19039c
>   looxcie-data1 [18/Dec/2011:04:30:15 +0000] 75.101.241.228
>   arn:aws:iam::062105025988:user/s3-user E938CC6E4B848BEA
>   REST.GET.BUCKET - "GET
>   /?delimiter=/&prefix=data/prod/looxciemp4/0/20/&max-keys=1000
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 - 672 - 44 41 "-" "-" -

Then I execute the command and get following result:

> root@test:/usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin# perl awstats.pl -update - config=www.awstats.apache.com
>   Create/Update database for config "/etc/awstats/awstats.www.awstats.apache.com.conf" by AWStats version 7.0 (build 1.971)
>   From data in log file "/var/log/httpd/access.log"...
>   Phase 1 : First bypass old records, searching new record...
>   Searching new records from beginning of log file...
>   Jumped lines in file: 0
>   Parsed lines in file: 1
>    Found 0 dropped records,
>    Found 0 comments,
>    Found 0 blank records,
>    Found 1 corrupted records,
>    Found 0 old records,
>    Found 0 new qualified records.

Can anyone help to figure it out?

===========================================

I found that the format "%logname" can not match such name 
   arn:aws:iam::062105025988:user/s3-user

It is wired, but "%lognamequot" is able to match "arn:aws:iam::062105025988:user/s3-user";
This is the cause of this problem;
But our system log file does include logname like arn:aws:iam::062105025988:user/s3-user;
Is there anyone can help to figure it out why it doesn't match it?

Comment: I changed the %logname to  %lognamequot and it can formate it now